# How to catch ParseError in Yii2 with PHP 7.1

Tags: php, exception, yii2, php-7

If I try the following code from command line, it catches the ParseError correctly:

```
<?php

$command = "[";

set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr) {
throw new Exception($errstr);
}, E_ALL);
try {
    eval("\$command = $command;");
} catch (ParseError $e) {
    echo 'Caught parse error: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
$ php eval.php 
PHP ParseError:  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']' in /home/ntibor/tmp/eval.php(9) : eval()'d code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/ntibor/tmp/eval.php:0
Caught parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']'
```

However if I'm using a very similar code in Yii2 it doesn't catch the ParseError:

```
   set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr) {
        throw new \yii\base\Exception($errstr);
    }, E_ALL);
    try {
        eval("\$config = $this->calculation_formula;");
    } catch (ParseError $e) {
        restore_error_handler();
        return $e->getMessage();
    } catch (\yii\base\Exception $e) {
        restore_error_handler();
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
    restore_error_handler();
```

I did not found anything in the vendor code of Yii2 regarding ParseError.
I do not see any differnce between the cli and apache2 php configuration either regarding E_PARSE.

Comment: [when eval"ing" the command it becomes `"\[ = [;"` PHP is expecting the close square bracket i.e. `"\[] = [];"`. `"\$config = $this->calculation_formula;"` could be something different to `"\$command = $command;`

Comment: That's clear. The problem is that the ParseError is not caught. I used "[" to fire a ParseError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i remember correctly, you need to add '\' to `ParseError` class declaration inside catch like this:

```
catch (\ParseError $e) {
    restore_error_handler();
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

It seems to be related to the Loader Yii2 uses, which affects the way classes from PHP are loaded.